# Error al momento de insertar datos en php

Tags: mysql

He estado intentado hacer pruebas para insertar datos a una base de datos con PHP, llevo intentandolo algo de tiempo y no le veo el error.

```html
<?php

include("conexion.php");

$db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $base ) or die ( "no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );

if(!$db){
    echo "fallo";
}else {
    echo "funciona base";
    
    
   
}


 $nom=$_POST['nombre']; 
 $ape=$_POST['apellido'];




   echo "<br>"; 
    
   $sql = "INSERT INTO `usuarios` (nombre, ap) VALUES ('$nom','$ape')";


   if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
      echo "Error: " .$sql. "<br>" . mysqli_error($db);
}
```

sin embargo, cada vez que lo ejecuto me sale el siguiente error:

> Error: INSERT INTO `usuarios` (nombre, ap) VALUES ('prueba','prub')

**Anexo la tabla SQL**

```html
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ap` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: `mysqli_query($conexion,$sql)`

Comment: Estás intentando insertar una tupla con un valor null (el ID) cuando ese campo está marcado como not null.

Comment: El problema ocurre cuando haces esto: **`$db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $base ) or die...;`**  porque `mysqli_select_db` sólo devuelve `TRUE` o `FALSE`, [ver Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php). O sea, **en `$db` no tienes realmente una referencia a la conexión, sino un booleano**. La conexión, supongo, está en esta variable `$conexion`, si no usas esa variable para consultar no funcionará, por eso ni siquiera tira el error al lado de la consulta, porque no usas la conexión real en ningún momento. Además no es necesario seleccionar la BD, lo puedes hacer al conectar.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, acabo de probarlo y efectivamente era eso, ni idea que mysqli_select_db solo devolvia booleanos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver este problema puedes utilizar consultas preparadas, lo hice de la siguiente forma:

1. Primero cree la tabla de la base de datos con el `ID` auto incrementable.

**TABLA `SQL`**

```
 CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL ,
    nombre varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ap varchar(50) NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT pk_usuarios PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

2. Luego, el siguiente codigo en php permite registrar un usuario por su nombre y apellido a la base de datos:

**CODIGO EN `PHP`**

```
<?php

$nom = $_POST['nombre'];
$ape = $_POST['apellido'];

require("conexion.php");

$conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Fallo al conectar con la BBDD";
    exit();
}

mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die ("No se encuntra la BBDD");

mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf-8");

$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, ap) VALUES (?,?)";

$resultado = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql);

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, 'ss',$nom, $ape);

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);

if($stmt == false){
    echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta";
}else{
    echo "Nombre y apellido registrado exitosamente.";

    mysqli_stmt_close($resultado);
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Te explico. Es logico que te de error.

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id`, `nombre`, `ap`) VALUES ('$nom','$ape')";
```

Ese error te aparece porque estas seleccionando 3 filas (`id`, `nombre`, `ap`) y solo le estas dando 2 valores que es nombre y el apellido.

Para mejorar la logica deberias quitar la fila id. de esta manera al ejecutar el php,  ingresara los valores de nombre y apellido en la tabla usuarios.

quedaría

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, ap) VALUES ('$nom','$ape')";
```

Espero haberte podido ayudar.

Comment: He quitado el id pero sigue arrojando el mismo error

Comment: podrías mostrar tu tabla usuarios? Para entender mejor el problema

Comment: Ya modifique la respuesta. Revisa. el nombre de la tabla y las filas no van con comillas.

Comment: Sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que tu campo id te esta pidiendo un dato, en este caso lo que puedes hacer es poner en la columna `id` el atributo `AUTO_INCREMENT`.